# How to Change the Spacing between Items in the `BottomNavigationBar()` in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

## 1. What I wish I could do

So far, my `BottomNavigationBar` looks ok (and simple), but, given that I have only 2 items in it, I would like to bring them a little bit closer together (and maybe to the right), so they are more easily reached. How do I do that? Is there a property that does the job? Maybe inside the `BottomNavigationBar` theme?

## 2. A Snippet

Here is what it looks like right now:

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      title: Text('Personal Data'),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.payment),
      title: Text('Contracts'),
    ),
  ],
  currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
  selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
  onTap: _onItemTapped,
),
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0),
              primaryColor: Colors.red,
                textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                    caption: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors
                            .white))), 
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                   child: BottomNavigationBar(
                      showSelectedLabels: false,
                      showUnselectedLabels: false,
                      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                      currentIndex: 0,
                      items: [
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                          title: Text(''),
                        ),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          title: Text(''),
                        ),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                          title: Text(''),
                        ),
                        BottomNavigationBarItem(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.folder_open,
                          ),
                          title: Text(''),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lSpc.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Upon inspecting the source code of `BottomNavigationBar` it looks like this isn't easily implemented due to this line here:

```dart
Widget _createContainer(List<Widget> tiles) {
  return DefaultTextStyle.merge(
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: tiles,
    ),
  );
}
```

It's in a private function within the class. Meaning that in order to change the `mainAxisAlignment` property of the `Row` that contains the tiles you'd have to recreate the entire class.

Comment: Well, I think they're likely adhering to Material Design rules for Material widgets. Personally I don't use Material or Cupertino Widgets and build what I want myself. It circumvents these kind of design limitations - which do have a purpose. Plus, we can't expect them to open up all the things. It'd become cumbersome to figure out what you want to tweak or not. What I wish they *would* do, however, is allow us to create subclasses that have access to/override private vars/functions/etc.

Comment: I *do* agree with not parametrizing everything, but spacing between items in the bottom navigation bar doesn't seem like that uncommon a use case... Anyway, I feel like they could maybe add a method to override some of the design rules, it would give us freedom and still abide to their design patterns.